# running my app on android studio 1.2.2 on a real usb device it does nothing why it's not running on the device ?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my smartphone it's already enabled for USB debugging.

When I run it the first times I had a window with some options one of them to run the app on running devices but the window was empty no running devices show.
So I did:

On my android studio I went to Run > Edit Confgiurations > Android Application > app > General > Target Device > USB Device

Now in the menu I select Run > Run > app 
I see on the bottom: Gradle Executing Task...

And when it finish nothing happen.

What else should I do  to make it run on my device ?

Comment: When I did in android studio on the bottom debug I see in the wlog window: Waiting for device.
USB device not found maybe it's something to do with the ADB I know that sometimes the ADB exe make problems ?

Comment: If you run `adb devices` from the command line, does it show any devices? The fact that the devices window in Studio was empty makes me think that your computer isn't recognizing your device. If it is a Windows computer, you may need to install the drivers.

Comment: Tanis I can see my smartphone G3 in the explorer I can get in see photos and stuff so it does recognize my phone. And where is the adb.exe located in ? What is the exact directory couldn't find it.

Comment: The explorer is irrelevant here- you need to have the right drivers for ADB to recognize it as a valid ADB target, not as a generic phone/storage device. The exact directory for ADB varies based on where you installed your Android SDK, but from your SDK root should be under "platform-tools."

Comment: I ran now adb devices and it show: List of devices attached
And that's it it doesn't show any devices.

Comment: That means that ADB doesn't see your device and you need to find the correct drivers for it.

Comment: Maybe I need to run and install packages in Android SDK Manager ? I didn't run it yet. And if I need to install which packages ?

Comment: Working after downloaded drivers thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem... When Windows install some automatic updates it sometimes screws the MTP driver. I just uninstalled the MTP driver , connected my device again ,and it installed the driver automatically